# I am a military spouse and I have a friend who is a veteran if we both show our military IDs is my friend allowed to come with me through security

Tags: air-travel

I am the spouse of an active duty military. I have a friend who is a veteran. She is taking me to the airport. If she shows her veteran military ID and I show my military spouse ID, is my friend allowed to come with me through security?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What country are you asking about?

Comment: I’m in Dayton ohio

Answer (score 4):

She would still need a Gate Pass or other valid reason to enter the terminal with you.

While Military ID's are valid for use with TSA, they alone do not get you through the checkpoint.

Comment: ...and also a valid ticket, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: So as long as I get her a gate pass she should be able to come with me through security checkpoint ?

Comment: @user72183 Yes, but they don't give them out just because you ask.  You would need some specific reason for your friend to accompany.  For example, you can get a Gate Pass to accompany a minor flying alone.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid that's exactly what a gate pass is - a ticket valid only for getting you through security. You can get them at the checkin desks, and they are used for accompanying passengers to the gate but not actually flying.

Comment: @user72183: There are scattered references online to gate passes being granted to the companions of military members who are about to be deployed.  However, most of these references are several years old, and they don't strictly apply to your situation.  You can always ask the gate staff, but you should be prepared for the answer to be no.